# count files in a script that match the passed in parameter

Tags: bash, parameters, scripting, expansion

When I run the following script in bash with no arguments it returns the correct number of files in this directory. But when I call it with `*.txt` it only returns with `1` (no mannner how many `*.txt` files there are). How can I get it to correctly expand the `*.something` in a script?

```
function files {
    ls -1 --file-type $1 | grep -v '/$' | wc -l
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcards are expanded before calling the function (unless you quote the argument). You should use `"$@"` to get all the arguments.

```
function files {
    ls --file-type "$@" | grep -c -v '/$'
}
```

Other changes:

1. You don't need `-1` when piping the output of `ls`. When output isn't to a terminal, it defaults to this option.
2. You don't need to pipe the output of `grep` to `wc -l`, you can use the `-c` option to print the count.